# ASP.NET sending gmail using smtp server

Tags: asp.net, email

I am trying to to create an email sending function for my website, but somehow I kept getting internal server errors with this, I have tried several different ways from other answers, but none of them works for me.

here is my ajax call:

```
self.sendEmail = function () {
    var data = { Email: self.Email() };
    showAjaxLoader();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/Account/EMail',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: getAuthHeader(tokenKey)
    }).done(function (data) {
        hideAjaxLoader();
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log("success");
    }).fail(showError);
}
```

and here is the controller for it:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Email")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Email(BindingModel model)
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password"),
            EnableSsl = true
        };
        client.Send("email@gmail.com", model.Email, "test", "testbody");
        return Request.CreateResponse<BindingModel>(HttpStatusCode.OK, model);
    }
```

the error is:
"POST http://localhost:52116/api/Account/Email 500 (Internal Server Error)"

"Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll"

Answer (score 0):

the status 500 means your data has been send to the "Email" function,and it has an error in the "Internal" , 
you can use  try.. catch.. to get the exception,and tell us what's the exception.

Comment: the exception is:"Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll"

Comment: you can console the Exception detail like this   ... Catch(Exception ex){ ex.ToString(); }